# Change of probability measure

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Can a standard normal random variable be made a unit mean Poisson distributed random variable by means of change of probability measure?

- Answer: No, because a normal probability measure is singular wrt. a Poisson probability measure.

Can someone clarify? I don't understand this.

Comment: Think about what change of probability measure means.

Comment: Yeah, I know. We go from one probability measure to an another by dividing the target PDF and the origin.